# Zip file not beeing created at obj\Debug\Package when building web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

i have this settings activated, but after the project buildt there is no zip file. Anyone got a clue why?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

build is not the same as publish.  You have to publish the web app to get it to create the zip.

Comment: thx for that, one more hour of my life wasted going down the wrong path again.